# What is evil-mode's equivalent to vim insert-mode completion?

Tags: evil

I'm making the move from Vim to Emacs + Evil-mode. I miss Vim's CTRL-X in insert mode to trigger completion of either words, tags, file paths, etc. 
I wonder if evil-mode has something similar?

Thanks

Comment: Evil doesn't do completion AFAIK, check on `company-mode`. It's a popular plug-able completion framework for emacs, example config: https://github.com/ideasman42/emacs-for-vimmers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use,

- In evil insert state, `evil-complete-next`(C-n) and `evil-complete-previous`(C-p) will complete words; `evil-complete-next-line` (C-x C-n) and `evil-complete-previous-line` (C-x C-p) will complete lines
- `company-mode` (https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode), a framework to complete anything
- `hippe-expand`, see https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HippieExpand  ; Here is my setup: https://github.com/redguardtoo/emacs.d/blob/f7a5a0b338c3fea4859b36d13d192af1614bb2c5/lisp/init-hippie-expand.el#L3)
- `eacl` (https://github.com/redguardtoo/eacl). It completes single line or multiple lines by grepping in project root
- `counsel-company.el` from `counsel` (https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper). It uses backend of `company-mode`, but with different UI
- Other commands from `counsel`. Currently `counsel-shell-history` is my favorite tool to re-use shell command history